# Informatica Developer

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter

How to convert normal date to Julian date?
How to convert localtimestamp to just HHMM in output?

Comment: show us your attemp. where do you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Julian Date format should be YYYYDDD.

```
julian_date = to_char(normal_date_col,'YYYYDDD') -- output should be a string column of length 7
```

output HHMM - you can do this using normal to_char.

```
hhmm_string_col=to_char(normal_date_col,'HHMI') -- output should be a string column of length 4
```