# Replace str in expression

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using localtimestamp format in expression transformation

Suppose my date is `30-oct-21 12.06.50.666340700 AM`

In informatica, expression transformation,
Output should be `12065066`
like *HHMISSMS* without any colon Or spaces.

Comment: What did you try? Did you see the docs about [REPLACESTR](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-0/transformation-language-reference/functions/replacestr.html), or [REG_REPLACE](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-0/transformation-language-reference/functions/reg_replace.html)?  Did you try to use them?  Can you show what you tried ?  (Maybe I should even add [TO_CHAR Format Strings](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-0/transformation-language-reference/dates/to_char-format-strings.html))

Comment: What did you do with the answers on your earlier questions? like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69776737/724039) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69662807/724039) ?   Why not respond to that unanswered questions if the answer is not clear ?

Comment: I tried REPLACESTR function here

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls use this to capture milliseconds.

```
To_char(datetime_col,'HH24MISSMS')
```

Output should be like 12065066.